# Trying to update root password on mysql or create a new user is giving me /mysql/user.MYD error

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I tried to make a `mysql_secure_installation` but after I enter the password is giving me this:

> ...Failed! Error: File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Connecting using `mysql` cli and trying to create a new user gives me the same.

Mysql is 5.7 and installed via Homebrew

Comment: Well does the file exist under your MySQL datadir?

Comment: Nope. I guess there is something else on :3306?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the database. Your error means, that the table in which users are stored doesn't exist.

Have a look in your /etc/my.cnf file. There should be an entry `datadir`. Make sure this directory is empty. Then do

```
# mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf
```

This creates the schema mysql and all necessary tables. After that you can do

```
# mysql_secure_installation
```