# abort while installing mysql

Tags: mysql, terminal

When I try to install mysql by running the following command:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

I see this output in my terminal:

[image]

What does it mean and how to solve it?

Comment: Try if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551682/usr-bin-mysql-secure-installation-and-mysql-install-db-do-not-work-and-cannot-i